# check duplicate entries in mysql while Inserting into MySql

Tags: php, mysql

This is my MySql table

```
-----------    --------------
location_id    location_name
-----------    --------------
   1              office
   2              hospital
   3              schools
```

I am running **INSERT INTO** query based on the location_id.

what i want is - 
if location id exists, return some message. else run INSERT query.

My Query

```
$sql = "SELECT location_id FROM tablename GROUP BY location_id HAVING count(*) > 1";
$rs=parent::_executeQuery($sql);
$rs = parent::getAll($rs);

if($rs)
{
     //RUN INSERT QUERY
}
else
{
     //RETURN SOME MESSAGE
}
```

Well, this is going inside **if** block everytime.

Comment: add where  condition to your query

Comment: $sql = "SELECT location_id FROM tablename WHERE location_id='".$location_id."'";

Comment: @kamlesh.bar adding `limit 1` will improve the performance of your query.

Comment: @jogesh_pi yes right you are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the if condition like this

```
if(count($rs)>0)
{
  // RETURN MESSAGE
}
else
{
    // INSERT QUERY
}
```

As `if($rs)` will check if the variable have a value or not and in your case it will have a value 0 if there are no location_id found.

So it will be better to check the count of the result.